# How do you use a bootstrap 3 table with ERB correctly?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

've got an Organization view that I want to render a partial into in order to show Users of the Organization with a bunch of additional features. To do so I have a Bootstrap panel set up, and inside this panel I want to render a bootstrap Table in order to show each user that belongs_to the Organization. I can get it working fine without the table css (just as separate div elements showing one User per line), but for some reason when I come to create a Table the thing keeps building entirely new tables (including the thead section) for each User object. Can you help?

Organization show page html:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <ul class="users">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading float-left">
        <% if current_user.admin? %>
        <%= link_to "Add more users", add_user_path(current_user.organization), class: "btn btn-large btn-success btn-panel" %>
        <% end %>
        <h2 class="panel-title">Users:</h2>
      </div>
        <div class="panel-body panel-height">
            <%= render partial: "users_index", collection: @users_index, as: :user %>
            <br></br>
        </div>
    </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The html for my users_index partial:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <%= link_to user.name, user %>
        </td>
        <td>
        <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
            <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                        data: {confirm: "You sure?" }, 
                                        class: "btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right"%>
        <% end %>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

The place where the users_index is defined (my Organization controller show function):

```
def show
 @organization = Organization.find(params[:id])
 @users_index = @organization.users
end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

In your Organization show page put the table code around the render line

```
    <div class="panel-body panel-height">
      <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
       <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <%= render partial: "users_index", collection: @users_index, as: :user %>
       </tbody>
      </table>
        <br></br>
    </div>
```

And your pratial will be like

```
<tr>
    <td>
    <%= link_to user.name, user %>
    </td>
    <td>
    <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
        <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                    data: {confirm: "You sure?" }, 
                                    class: "btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right"%>
    <% end %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

look, when you are rendering a collection Rails looks for a partial that matches and render it for each item in the collection, and that's why you get a table for each user, what you want is only a row in the table for each user so the partial only contains the table row code.